# Cannot access SDcard (ExternalStorageDirectoryPath points to /storage/emulated/0)

Tags: react-native, android-sdcard, sd-card, android-external-storage

I am developing a react native app for android, which allow user to write files to an external SDcard on Android Pie. I have used React-native fs and react-native fetch-blob libraries. The problem is that i can not get the correct path to my external SDcard. I have tried using  RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath and RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath. They all give path as "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.storage/files". this path does not save file in SDcard it save the file in internal memory. 
I'm using Android 9 and have given permission for read and write in AndroidManifest.xml.
Any suggestion to how to write file to SD card and does android Pie support read and write to external SD Card?

Comment: Did you debug it on a real device? From path it looks like you are running the app on an AVD so there's no external storage obviously.

Comment: yes. I have run it on my smart phone. result is same

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue